# Workflow history reset whenever triggered

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

I'm working on SP Foundation 2010

I have a task list and whenever the task is reassigned to another person I need to track it. I've created a column called old-assigned to so whenever the task is edited, the workflow compares the new assignment to the old, and logs the change. Then I took the workflow status field and put that in my view so a user could easily see the workflow logs which would track all assignments and reassignments for a specific task.

However, the workflow status page and history is only showing me the latest log entry and not all previous entries. I don't understand why.

These are my workflow and settings:

[image: screenshot]